# How to run bash file for (different directory) as input automatically

Tags: linux, bash

I have a bash file which takes 5 inputs.

```
Input1 = file1
Input2 = file2
Input3 = directory1
Input4 = func
Input5 = 50
```

input 4 and 5 are always the same, never change.

file1 and file 2 are located inside directory1

directory1 is located inside a code directory

```
/code/directory1/file1
/code/directory1/file2
```

and there are many directories with the same structure directory(1-70) inside the code folder

```
/code/directory1/*
/code/directory2/*
/code/directory3/*
...
/code/directory70/*
```

In order to run the bash file, I have to run the command from terminal 70 times :<

Is there a way to automatically run all these folders at once?

UPDATE: the directory(1-7) each one has a different name e.g bug1, test, 4-A and so on. Even the files are different e.g. bug1.c hash.c

```
/code/bug1/bug1.c
code/bug1/hash.c
```

Comment: `for d in /code/directory* ; do yourscript.sh $d/file1 $d/file2 $d func 50 ; done`, assuming that file1 and file2 are in all these directories.

Comment: Also check out the `find` command if you need something more complex than a single directory wildcard.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
for dirs in $(ls -F /code | grep '/')
do
    eval files=( "$(ls -1 ${dirs})" )
    <ShellScript>.sh "${dirs}${files[0]}" "${dirs}${files[1]}" "${dirs%/}" func 50
done
```